# JSON timestamp to insert into time series MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

/action/insertOne in the MongoDB API works like a charm for standard data, but we are struggling to do the same for a time series database.
Without fail, we are getting

`‘t’ must be present and contain a valid BSON UTC datetime value`

no matter how we are trying to format the timestamp.

The only API doc reference made to timestamps we find is:
`{ "T": 1565545664, "I": 1}`

None of the other timestamp formats used with MongoDB, seem to apply to JSON payloads.

Would be grateful for any pointers into how to approach this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ "T": 1565545664, "I": 1}` looks like a Timestamp value, not a UTC datetime.

According to the [BSON spec](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) those are different types.

Since the UTC datetime type contains the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970, you might try one of these:

`{"t": 1565545664000}`
`{"t": {"$date": 1565545664000}}`

Comment: Great, 
{"t": {"$date": 1565545664000}}
did it.